# How to remove Accept-Encoding header from the header part in $http.get angularjs

Tags: http-headers

I want to remove access-encoding header from $http.get request. Tried via following, but not any luck.

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Encoding'];
$http({ method: 'GET', url: apiUrl, data: '', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept-encoding': null } });
```

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Please use markup (backticks) to make your `code` readable.

Answer (score 0):

For the very same purpose, I am following this fiddle,
http://fiddle.jshell.net/X2p7r/344/

also as per documentation of AngularJS

To add headers for an HTTP method other than POST or PUT, simply add a new object with the lowercased HTTP method name as the key, e.g.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'My-Header' : 'value' }
```

I am able to modify 'Accept' and 'Content-Type' headers but not able to do same with Accept-Encoding, doesn't change no matter what I try it remains same. 
Thanks in Advance for any help.

Edit:https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
I tried to set Accept-Encoding according to the ways mention in above link.